# Android Local Notifications

Tags: android, notifications, android-sqlite, android-notifications

What I am looking at doing is implementing local notifications. The idea is that dates are stored in an SQL file on the phone and when the current date reaches the date before the date in the SQL file i am looking at notifying the user with a message.

I have done a lot of research into this and have found things relating to Alarms and services. I am now really confused and have no idea which root to take. Could someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is use an AlarmManager for this that broadcasts a notification. You won't need to set the date in a database and manage it...just set the date in the AlarmManager. I've created a class for this which has a function for setting the time the alarm should go off, as well as receiving the broadcast then building the notification.

```
public class MyAlarmManager extends BroadcastReceiver {
private Context mContext;
private AlarmManager mAlarmManager;

public MyAlarmManager() {}

public MyAlarmManager(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
}

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
     PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "YOUR TAG");
     //Acquire the lock
     wl.acquire();

     //You can do the processing here.      
     buildNotification(context);

     //Release the lock
     wl.release();
 }

public void setReminder(long time) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyAlarmManager.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, intent, 0);
    mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pi); //time is in milliseconds
}

public void buildNotification(Context context) {
    long[] vibrate = { 0, 100, 200, 300 };

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!")
            .setVibrate(vibrate)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, YourLaunchActivity.class);

    // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
    // started Activity.
    // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
    // your application to the Home screen.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ConferencesActivity.class);
    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    int randomId = 1000303;
    mNotificationManager.notify(randomId, mBuilder.build());
}
```

}

Then be sure to add this in your manifest and use whatever your app package name is:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.myapp.MyAlarmManager"></receiver>
```

Hope that helps!